# Using bulk_update_mappings in SQLAlchemy to update multiple rows with different values

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables Foo and Bar. I just added a new column `x` to the Bar table which has to be populated using values in Foo

```
class Foo(Base):
    __table__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Bar(Base):
    __table__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'), nullable=False)
```

One straightforward way to do it would be iterating over all the rows in Bar and then updating them one-by-one, but it takes a long time (there are more than 100k rows in Foo and Bar)

```
for b, foo_x in session.query(Bar, Foo.x).join(Foo, Foo.id==Bar.foo_id):
    b.x = foo_x
session.flush()
```

Now I was wondering if this would be right way to do it -

```
mappings = []
for b, foo_x in session.query(Bar, Foo.x).join(Foo, Foo.id==Bar.foo_id):
    info = {'id':b.id, 'x': foo_x}
    mappings.append(info)
session.bulk_update_mappings(Bar, mappings)
```

There are not much examples on `bulk_update_mappings` out there. The docs suggest

> All those keys which are present and are not part of the primary key
>   are applied to the SET clause of the UPDATE statement; the primary key
>   values, which are required, are applied to the WHERE clause.

So, in this case `id` will be used in the `WHERE` clause and then that would be updates using the `x` value in the dictionary right ?

Comment: @Chris, I assume this works for you and you just want to make sure that the way is correct from a approach perspective?

Comment: Yep, exactly ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The approach is correct in terms of usage. The only thing I would change is something like below

```
mappings = []
i = 0

for b, foo_x in session.query(Bar, Foo.x).join(Foo, Foo.id==Bar.foo_id):
    info = {'id':b.id, 'x': foo_x}
    mappings.append(info)
    i = i + 1
    if i % 10000 == 0:
        session.bulk_update_mappings(Bar, mappings)
        session.flush()
        session.commit()
        mappings[:] = []

session.bulk_update_mappings(Bar, mappings)
```

This will make sure you don't have too much data hanging in memory and you don't do a too big insert to the DB at a single time

Comment: Great! I have million data to be updated and there is poor connection between sql and backend. It seems the update process hang forever. Thanks for the suggestion of splitting data.

Comment: Is there any way to specify where clause as other fields than primary key?

Comment: @Mehrdad, i would suggest to open a new query on the same and post a link here if needed. As the problems are totally different

Comment: @TarunLalwani Good suggestion, I did that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534134/sqlalchemy-bulk-update-with-custom-where-clause

Comment: By default, session has autoflush enabled, so there's no need to flush explicitly every 10k records

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to this question, but for those searching for more performance when updating/inserting using both methods: `bulk_update_mappings` and `bulk_insert_mappings`, just add the `fast_executemany` to your `engine` as follows:

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string, fast_executemany=True)
```

You can use that parameter in `sqlalchemy` versions above `1.3`. This parameter comes from `pyodbc` and it will for sure speed up your bulk requests.