# How to update records when many fields in Flask. Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the record in the sqlite database, the values ​​that come in the query from the frontend:

```
data: [{"cnt_doc":"17","code":"111","contragent":"Name1","contragent_id":2,"created_date":"Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:54:37 GMT","date_operation":null,"id":2,"rezerv":"23","status":"Status1","status_id":1,"stellag":"67","storage":"NameStorage","storage_id":2,"sum_operation":"100","timestamp":"Mon, 17 Jun 2019 18:54:37 GMT","type":2,"type_id":2,"id_type":0}]
```

In my Flask application I do this:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify, request
from app import app, db
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from app.models import Operation

...

@app.route('/operation', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def operation():   
        method = request.args.get('method')       
        if method == 'Update':
            data = request.form.get("data")
            try:
                objFormat = json.loads(data)
                for key in objFormat:
                    dict_upd = key

                operat = Operation.query.filter_by(id=int(dict_upd['id'])).first()
                for key in dict_upd.keys():
                    setattr(operat, key, dict_upd[key])

                Operation.query.update(operat)#
                db.session.commit()
                jsonFormat = jsonify(dict_upd)
                dictOut = {"data": dict_upd, "meta": {"success": "true"}}

                return (dictOut)
            except SQLAlchemyError as e:
                return jsonify('Error update record in db', exc_info=e)
```

In my case, I get an error when executing `Operation.query.update (operat)` and I strongly doubt that the `operat` object has the necessary structure to execute the update.
Give an example or correct mine to most concisely and correctly update the records when there are many fields requiring updating.

Performing update records in this form is successfully performed, but has a very cumbersome structure:

```
operat = Operation.query.filter_by(id = int(dict_upd['id'])).update(
                                        {'date_operation': dict_upd.date_operation},
                                        {'code': dict_upd.code},
                                        {'status_id': dict_upd.status_id},
                                        {'status': dict_upd.status},
                                        {'type_id': dict_upd.type_id},
                                        {'type': dict_upd.type},
                                        {'storage_id': dict_upd.storage_id},
                                        {'storage': dict_upd.storage},
                                        {'contragent_id': dict_upd.contragent_id},
                                        {'contragent': dict_upd.contragent},
                                        {'sum_operation': dict_upd.sum_operation},
                                        {'rezerv': dict_upd.rezerv},
                                        {'cnt_doc': dict_upd.cnt_doc},
                                        {'stellag': dict_upd.stellag},
                                        )
```

Therefore, I am trying to shorten my design of updating records.
Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extend the dictionary with the operation id, you can use SQLAlchemy's `bulk_update_mappings` to just update them in the database with very little overhead from the ORM. I don't have many numbers, but I can tell from experience that it's going to be a lot faster and less cumbersome. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49474697/5015356) and [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings)

```py
def operation():
  method = request.args.get('method')
  if method == 'Update':
    data = request.form.get("data")
    try:
      objFormat = json.loads(data)
      db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(Operation, objFormat)
      db.session.commit()
      jsonFormat = jsonify(dict_upd)
      dictOut = {"data": dict_upd, "meta": {"success": "true"}}

      return (dictOut)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
      return jsonify('Error update record in db', exc_info=e)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the dictionary to update function ([docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update)):

```
operat = Operation.query.filter_by(id = int(dict_upd['id'])).update(dict_upd)
```

You can also use [merge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) to create or update object in database:

```
operat = db.session.merge(Operation( **dict_upd))
```