# SQLAlchemy Bulk update with custom where clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulkupdate

using bulk_update_mappings, the approach is:

> All those keys which are present and are not part of the primary key are applied to the SET clause of the UPDATE statement; the primary key values, which are required, are applied to the WHERE clause.

Is there any way to change this rule? 
I mean to specify a custom where clause as:

```
update Bar set name='a' where family='b' and code = 10
update Bar set name='b' where family='c' and code = 11
update Bar set name='c' where family='d' and code = 12
........
update Bar set name='aaaa' where family='bbbb' and code = 10000
```

Comment: Bulk update is when the name to be set is different for each operation, in this case why don't you better fire a direct query itself on `Bar` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the sample code was just for clearing my question. I changed it