# Efficient Bulk Insert/Update Operations on Existing Table Using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I am looking to insert/update a large volume of data stored in either a list of tuples or list of dictionaries into an **existing table** using SQLAlchemy. What is the most efficient way to do this?

What I have right now is this,

```
session_maker = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker()
session_maker .configure(bind=engine)
inspector = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)
session = session_maker()

meta_data = sqlalchemy.MetaData(engine)
MyTable = sqlalchemy.Table('MyTable', meta_data, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

MyTable.insert().execute([{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}])
```

I have also heard of `bulk_insert_mappings()` and `bulk_save_objects()`. I would, however, like to avoid creating any other objects as explained here [Bulk insert with SQLAlchemy ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659142/bulk-insert-with-sqlalchemy-orm) and use either a list of tuples or dictionaries as mentioned above.

How can I do bulk updates?

Comment: Searching for previous questions and answers mentioning "upsert" may give you some ideas.

Comment: I am not looking to perform upserts. I am looking for efficient ways to implement bulk-inserts and bulk-updates.

Comment: And what leads you to believe that previous answers about upserts would not offer valuable insights regarding "efficient ways to implement bulk-inserts and bulk-updates"?

Comment: Yes, understood. I have done what you have suggested. From what I tried, `.insert().execute()` seems to be the best (in terms of performance) for bulk inserts. Do you know what I could use for bulk updates, again with a similar list of dictionaries? The only thing I could get to work was `session.bulk_update_mappings()`, but this is really slow.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `bulk_update_mappings/bulk_insert_mappings`. Also, you have an option of using a parameter called `fast_executemany` on the `engine` creation. Please, refer to my answer at:
[Using bulk_update_mappings in SQLAlchemy to update multiple rows with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272316/using-bulk-update-mappings-in-sqlalchemy-to-update-multiple-rows-with-different/74103044#74103044).