# PostgreSQL + Django update large table taking ages to run a simple update

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table with around 47millions entries. I need to update this table for around 3mil entries very fast, for this I use `type_id` and an int inside a range to select records and then update the value on another field, while excluding another record.

```sql
UPDATE "table_name" SET "changes" = 12 WHERE ("table_name".
"type_id" = 78 AND "table_name"."rank" BETWEEN 2 AND 2238079 AND NOT ("table_name"."id" = 55423921))
```

This query was automatically generated by [Django using the `update` method on a `QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update), but it follows the bahavior described above and can be changed to what ever is more efficient.

The reason I store all those records in the same table is to dynamically add new `type_id` inside without having to create a new table for each (assuming doing so would improve the speed).

Currently the table has multiple indexes, but let's list the fields first:

```sql
id (PK);
type (foreign key containing ID + type name);
score (BigInt);
score_data (jsonb fr metadatas);
changes (IntField);
rank (IntField, used for range selection);
user (foreign key for the user related to this record);
```

There are different indexes :

- BTree for field `score` and `rank`
- type for it's PK, probably a BTree (it's the default index)
- user, same as type

As you probably have guessed I'm making a leaderboard system which stores its rank and changes directly inside the scores.

My questions are:

- Should I split the tables into each different type to improve speed
- Should I do the above and make the `rank` a PK
- Is there a better index for like an ordered table where I could just order by `score` and don't bother with rank and changes ?
- Is there a simple method to improve the update query speed with rawsql ?

Timings for the included query was 4 minutes to complete which is extremely long.

I'm all open for sugestions and this table and whole structure can be changed a bit (as long as we keep the same kind of stored data).

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement? (obs. the query will be executed!) And the exact DDL for the table and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your question

Comment: Sure, i will do that in a moment

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361291/slow-simple-update-query-on-postgresql-database-with-3-million-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the best way for you is to make a materialized view-table with this query.

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
    SELECT id as user,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC, some_field DESC) AS rank
    FROM table_name WHERE score > 0
)
    
SELECT rank::integer, user::integer
FROM RankedTable
```

And then you will have a view-table which will automatically update data in case of changing in the main table, it's much faster and you don't have to update the rank field everytime.

Comment: Hey, that looks like a good idea, just tried it out on a small dataset and it works great. I'll set it up for my gigantic table but rather than having 1 view i'll create one for each data group so ranks can stay unique.

Comment: Looks good so far, updating is fast but fetching data from it is "slow" example would be `SELECT * FROM public.test
WHERE rank = 58
LIMIT 100` took 01:05 to complete (on around 3.7mil records), constructing it took 20secs which is okay

Comment: after a bit of research and docs reading I chosen to create materialized views which keep the speed of the above query but include fast fetching with the only downside being that it uses disk space, the fact that matviews need "manal" updating is actually a good thing in my case